# NullPointerException when trying to get URI with FileProvider(Android)

Tags: android, image, android-intent, nullpointerexception, uri

i want to take a Photo after clicking on a button. But i am getting `NullPointerException` when trying to get `URI` with `FileProvider`.

**Here is my ErrorCode:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)

    at ibas.orosol.BildActivity.takePicture(BildActivity.java:86)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

***The Problem-Line seems to be:***

```
mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplication().getApplicationContext(),
            "ibas.provider", file);
```

Here´s my ***Code***:

```
public void takePicture(View view) throws IOException {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    try{
        File file =  createImageFile();

        mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplication().getApplicationContext(),
                "ibas.provider", file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    String path = "sdcard/orosol/captured_image.jpg";
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.i("uri-data", "Uri: " + mUri.toString());


        mBitmap = getBitmapFromUri(mImageView,BildActivity.this,mUri);


        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    }

}
```

My Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ibas.orosol">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="ibas.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MenuActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HeizoelActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MenuActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BildActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MenuActivity" />
        >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FacebookActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MenuActivity" />
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".KontakteActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MenuActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".UeberUnsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MenuActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

***Provider in res/xml***

```
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/> </paths>
```

Any Idea where the Problem Occurs?

Comment: did you add xml file in res/xml folder?

Comment: yes i had added. Still same problem.

Comment: post it........

Comment: post your full manifest it would be helpful

Comment: getApplication().getApplicationContext() == null ? Or file== null ? Check before use.

Comment: Show your xml paths file too.

Comment: Try to change `mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(BildActivity.this,
                "ibas.provider", file);`

Comment: i have added xml

Comment: i added full manifest

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The provider tag is outside of the  application tag in the manifest file .

You should add it inside the `<application></application>` tag

```
 <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="ibas.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: I have created the xml folder under res and added provider_paths.xml file. Then i included the provide inside the application but error indicated on "@xml/provider_paths"

Comment: You are a winner, thank you. The examples on Android show bits and pieces and and lack full code unless you go into sample code you cannot uncover these issues.

Comment: You're my rescue sir!

Comment: It worked for me!

Comment: I've already done this, yet I still get the error.

Comment: @wesleyfranks check if the authority you pass to  getUriForFile is the same as declared in the manifest; you will also get the same error if it is different